# Conditions for compositions involving one analytic function to be analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Suppose that I have two functions, $f,g: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, of which $f$ is analytic. What can be proven of $g$ if $f \circ g$ is analytic? If $g \circ f$ is analytic?

Basically, what are the bounds on $g$ such that compositions involving $f,g$ are analytic?

Comment: Nothing much really. $g$ could be extremely crazy. For example, look at $f(z) =\sin(\pi z)$, and $g$ an arbitrary integer-valued function. The composition $f \circ g$ is then constantly 0.

Comment: If $f$ is zero then $g$ does not have to be even continous. But if derivative of $f$ is not zero at a given point, then locally $f$ is inertable so $g$ has to be analitic as well.

Comment: assuming $f$ nonconstant, you need $g$ to be continuous and then you can deduce analyticity from $f\circ g$ analytic under mild conditions on the preimage of $g$ of countable sets; for the other one, one gets that $g$ is analytic except at countably many points without any conditions so with continuity, you deduce $g$ analytic everywhere

Comment: @salcio you need continuity of $g$ for your claim as if you take $f(z)=z^2$, you can pick any square root you want (so $g$ can be totally discontinuous outside $0$ by picking randomly $\pm$ square roots) so still $f\circ g$ is entire